# How to analyze method calls and objects of other classes used in a java class programmatically

Tags: java, object, methods

i need to detect if a class relies on another class programatically,to detect inappropriate intimacy code smell(i want to analyze other java programs ,using my program).Any directions on
how to achieve this will be a  great help.

And

1. How to identify all the objects created in a java program?
2. How to identify all the called methods in a java program?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to use what's already there instead of building something yourself. Especially if you're not very familiar with the internals of Java and the JVM.

Have a look at JDepend: http://clarkware.com/software/JDepend.html

Answer (score 0):

Use a profiler as [JConsole](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/management/jconsole.html) or [VisualVM](http://visualvm.java.net/intro.html). With the use of profilers you can pretty much see everything that happens at runtime.

Comment: i need to analyze these programatically

Comment: @RoshanaSheri can you give us an example of what you want to do with this informatino?

Comment: Do I understand it correctly that you want a program that analyzes another program?

Comment: If it's to detect bad code like you say in your original post, I would look in the java code if that's possible. Otherwise it seems like you just want to write a profiler-like application. I can only wish you good luck with that!

Answer (score 0):

One way i think of is using logger, Put some log statement in the construct and in the methods you want to monitor. So through logs you can find out the objects created and methods accessed

Comment: i need to analyze different classes in my program and i need to identify what objects are created in that class and what methods are called.

Comment: i pass a java file path to my program,then i want to analyze it.

Answer (score 0):

I have found very useful the [ObjectWeb asm-all](http://asm.ow2.org/index.html) Java bytecode manipulation and analysis library, also known as `asm-all.jar`

It allows you to convert any *.jar application into equivalent XML file. You can fully inspect the application structure, change it in the XML format and convert back into *.jar file

In order to use the XML files you'll need to understand what it contains. [Oracle's The Java® Virtual Machine Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se8/html/index.html) is very good reference to start with

BTW: one thing you can do with this tool is to instrument the bytecode so that it creates runtime profiling information - which methods were called and by whom (as suggested by @upog)